# How do I capture the href id of my index.html page into my views.py file and use it to render my 2nd html page in Django

Tags: python, html, django, hyperlink

**my HTML code**

```
<html>
{% for d in name %}
<li><a id = {{d}} alt={{d|slugify }} href ="/hindi_guitarchords/{{d}}" 
class = "click">{{d}}</a> </li>
{% endfor %}
</html>
```

**url.py code**

```
url(r'^hindi_guitarchords/(?P<d>.*)/$', 'guitarchordsapp.views.hindi_guitarchords'),
```

**views.py**

```
def hindi_guitarchords(request, d):
    msg = request.POST.get('d')
    #msg= get_object_or_404(Post,slug=d)

    return render_to_response('hindi_guitarchords.html',{'song_name':msg})
```

Let me know if I'm missing something

Comment: `d` is being sent as a parameter to the view. You dont need the request.POST

Comment: Thanks a lot karthikr, worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `msg = request.POST.get('d')` with `msg = d`

Comment: Thanks Geo. I figured it out